# combine javascript progress bar with another javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript progressbar:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
            value: 37
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have another javascript that automaticaly gets a value from a file:

```
 <script>
    var time = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {time : time},
            url: "fileupdate.php",
            success: function (data) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data)
                if (result.content) {
                    $('#file_content') .html(result.content);
                }
                time = result.time;
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

How can I add the js for the progress bar to this script so that the value for the progress bar can automaticaly update?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, making an ajax request inside an interval which is called each second is calling for trouble. At least use a timeout and recall it once request it is completed

Comment: @A. Wolff Well I'm sure it would help if I new what I was doing. The ajax stuff is what another user helped me with. If you think it could be improved i would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Coenster Are you trying to loop the ajax call indefinitly?

Comment: @JF it. Yes. The file that get the value for the progress bar(that is not working, hence this question) gets updated every second or two seconds.

Comment: @Coenster When should it end?? ..

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the request every second.. Is this what you want? This will stack the request if not finished over and over..

What you should probally do, as per A.Wolff's suggestion is to call the function every time a ajax call is complete.. see code below:

See this blog: http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/

```
function doAjaxCall(){
  $.ajax({
   xhr: function(){
   var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
   //Upload progress
   xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
   if (evt.lengthComputable) {
     var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
     //Do something with upload progress
     console.log(percentComplete);
     }
   }, false);
 //Download progress
   xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
     if (evt.lengthComputable) {
       var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
     //Do something with download progress
       console.log(percentComplete);
     }
   }, false);
   return xhr;
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/",
  data: {},
  success: function(data){
     doAjaxCall(); //THIS WILL CALL THE FUNCTION AGAIN IF THE CALL IS SUCCESSFUL.
  }
 });
}
```